# Import .sqlserver file in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have SQL Server 2016 on my system and I want to import a file with extension `.sqlserver` into it to create a database.

What is the `SqlCmd` command for this?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/sqlcmd-start-the-utility?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I'm not familiar with that extension, what is in the file? Is it a bunch of SQL code, a database backup or something else?

Comment: its a database schema

Comment: A database schema is just a name to group objects (like a folder in windows explorer), what is in the actual file?

Comment: I think he means that the file contains database script which create schema only. When you use Generate Scripts Task from SSMS, you can choose between data/shcema/data and schema, and he wants to say that only schema was scripted

Comment: yes, it contains database DDL scripts

Comment: Does sqlcmd require a .sql extension? Can't you just use the same code and point to a different file? I guess I have never tried doing that. Like `sqlcmd -S [server] -E -i yourfile.sqlserver`

Comment: Sqlcmd eats any extension

Comment: There's no such thing a `.sqlserver` file format. This is an extension someone has added to file formatted another way, and you'll need to figure out how the file is actually formatted. I'd start by opening it in a text edit, to see if it has SQL command text or binary data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"**There's no such thing a `.sqlserver` file format**"  Thanks to @@Joel Coehoorn

We have files with extension `.sql` file

From the `command prompt`, start up `sqlcmd`:

```
sqlcmd -S <server> -i C:\<your file here>.sql
```

Replace `<server>` with the location of your SQL server name and `<your file here>` with the name of your script.

If you're using a SQL instance the syntax is:

```
sqlcmd -S <server>\instance.
```

Here is the list of all arguments you can pass `sqlcmd`:

```
Sqlcmd            [-U login id]          [-P password]
  [-S server]            [-H hostname]          [-E trusted connection]
  [-d use database name] [-l login timeout]     [-t query timeout] 
  [-h headers]           [-s colseparator]      [-w screen width]
  [-a packetsize]        [-e echo input]        [-I Enable Quoted Identifiers]
  [-c cmdend]            [-L[c] list servers[clean output]]
  [-q "cmdline query"]   [-Q "cmdline query" and exit] 
  [-m errorlevel]        [-V severitylevel]     [-W remove trailing spaces]
  [-u unicode output]    [-r[0|1] msgs to stderr]
  [-i inputfile]         [-o outputfile]        [-z new password]
  [-f  | i:[,o:]] [-Z new password and exit] 
  [-k[1|2] remove[replace] control characters]
  [-y variable length type display width]
  [-Y fixed length type display width]
  [-p[1] print statistics[colon format]]
  [-R use client regional setting]
  [-b On error batch abort]
  [-v var = "value"...]  [-A dedicated admin connection]
  [-X[1] disable commands, startup script, environment variables [and exit]]
  [-x disable variable substitution]
  [-? show syntax summary]
```